# Add text to three js modal box

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a onClick function which adds a 3D modal on top of a box.
I want to add text to this box:

But I can't get it to work:

```
function onClick(object) {
            if (uiPlane !== undefined) {
                scene.remove(uiPlane);
                scene.remove(t)
                uiPlane = undefined;
            } else {
                var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(6, 2, 1);
                var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
                    color: new THREE.Color("rgb(242, 242, 242)"),
                    side: THREE.DoubleSide
                });

                uiPlane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
                uiPlane.name = 'dialog_' + object.name;

                if (object.name === 'Button_7' || object.name === 'Button_12') {




                    uiPlane.position.x = object.position.x - 3.75;
                    uiPlane.position.y = object.position.y;
                    uiPlane.position.z = object.position.z;
                    t=createText("Hello world!Hello world!Hello world!Hello world!",uiPlane.position.x,uiPlane.position.y,uiPlane.position.z,"left","16px Arial",205,205,'black');

                } else if (object.name === 'Button_6' || object.name === 'Button_8') {




                    uiPlane.position.x = object.position.x + 3.75;
                    uiPlane.position.y = object.position.y;
                    uiPlane.position.z = object.position.z - 0.1;
                    t=createText("Hello world!Hello world!Hello world!Hello world!",uiPlane.position.x,uiPlane.position.y,uiPlane.position.z,"left","16px Arial",205,205,'black');

                } else if (object.name === 'Button_11') {




                    uiPlane.position.x = object.position.x + 0.1;
                    uiPlane.position.y = object.position.y - 0.5;
                    uiPlane.position.z = object.position.z - 3.6;
                    t=createText("Hello world!Hello world!Hello world!Hello world!",uiPlane.position.x,uiPlane.position.y,uiPlane.position.z,"left","16px Arial",205,205,'black');

                    uiPlane.rotateY(89.5);
                } else if (object.name === 'Button_10') {




                    uiPlane.position.x = object.position.x - 0.1;
                    uiPlane.position.y = object.position.y - 0.5;
                    uiPlane.position.z = object.position.z + 3.5;
                    t=createText("Hello world!Hello world!Hello world!Hello world!",uiPlane.position.x,uiPlane.position.y,uiPlane.position.z,"left","16px Arial",205,205,'black');

                    uiPlane.rotateY(-89.5);
                } else if (object.name === 'Button_9') {




                    uiPlane.position.x = object.position.x;
                    uiPlane.position.y = object.position.y - 0.5;
                    uiPlane.position.z = object.position.z + 3.5;
                    t=createText("Hello world!Hello world!Hello world!Hello world!",uiPlane.position.x,uiPlane.position.y,uiPlane.position.z,"left","16px Arial",205,205,'black');

                    uiPlane.rotateY(-89.5);
                } else if (object.name === 'Button_3') {




                    uiPlane.position.x = object.position.x;
                    uiPlane.position.y = object.position.y - 0.5;
                    uiPlane.position.z = object.position.z + 3.5;
                    t=createText("Hello world!Hello world!Hello world!Hello world!",uiPlane.position.x,uiPlane.position.y,uiPlane.position.z,"left","16px Arial",205,205,'black');

                    uiPlane.rotateY(-89.5);
                } else {




                    uiPlane.position.x = object.position.x + 3.75;
                    uiPlane.position.y = object.position.y;
                    uiPlane.position.z = object.position.z + 0.25;
                    t=createText("Hello world!Hello world!Hello world!Hello world!Hello world!Hello world!Hello world!Hello world!Hello world!Hello world!Hello world!Hello world!Hello world!Hello world!Hello world!Hello world!",uiPlane.position.x,uiPlane.position.y,uiPlane.position.z,"left","16px Arial",205,205,'black');
                }
                scene.add(uiPlane);
                scene.add(t);
            }
```

I would expect something like uiPlane.text or innerHTML or html or anything but none of those work.

EDIT:

I found a function which adds a Canvas with text. What are the correct options ?

```
function createText(text, x, y, z, textAlign, font, width, height, color){
            var textHolder = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
            var ctext = textHolder.getContext('2d');
            textHolder.width = width;
            textHolder.height = height;
            ctext.fillStyle = color;
            ctext.font = "500px Arial";
            ctext.textAlign = textAlign;
            ctext.fillText(text, width/2, height);


            var tex = new THREE.Texture(textHolder);
            // tex.needsUpdate = true;

            var mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: tex, overdraw: false});
            mat.transparent = true;
            mat.map.needsUpdate = true;

            var textBoard = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1, 1), mat);
            textBoard.position.x = x-2;
            textBoard.position.y = y+1;
            textBoard.position.z = z;


            return textBoard;
        }
```

Comment: Is it acceptable to use a canvas with text as a texture for a plane?

Comment: Probably. Can you help me out @prisoner849 ?

Comment: Hee @prisoner849 I found a function to add a canvas, but the text gets stretched... :(

Comment: Maybe this kinda text? https://threejs.org/examples/?q=text#webgl_geometry_text_shapes